# Downloading contents of a directory via http without knowing the file names

Tags: http, download

I know the address where some zip files are but I don't know the name of all the files.

Like:

```
https://joomlab.org/archive/templates/joomshaper/
```

If I knew the names I could write them after the address and download the files.

Like:

```
https://joomlab.org/archive/templates/joomshaper/js_giver_YSMWHNZv2J.zip
```

How can I download all the files in that folder without knowing the name of the files?

Comment: Unless the server has directory content listing active (which it hasn't in this case) you simply can't.

Comment: ^ dirbuster ftw :P

Comment: how can i dear milney?